# TRY... CATCH with warnings

Tags: sql-server-2012, try-catch, procedure

I have a SQL Server 2012 procedure that occasionally has issues such as this:

> String or binary data would be truncated.

I have a TRY... CATCH block similar to below setup already in the procedure but this code doesn't catch warnings. Any tips on how to rollback the transaction if there is a warning?

```
BEGIN TRY  
     { sql_statement | statement_block }  
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
     [ { sql_statement | statement_block } ]  
END CATCH  
[ ; ]
```

Thank you

Comment: I tried this on SQL 2012 and in the case of warning control goes to CATCH section. I have a PRINT command there and I see it prints

Comment: If it's an error level below 10, it doesn't go to the catch

Comment: for me it is Level 16. Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1

Comment: Warnings or informational messages that have a severity of 10 or lower. From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: OK, but this warning has severity level 16 so it will go to CATCH. If you not catch it what is the exact message you get?